Loop grid height - i cant aliagnt button and text above image are
I have tried everything for a week now. But I can't get all the heights in my loop grid to be the same. I think I should do something with CSS but I don't know any programming language. I tried for example this video: https://youtu.be/PGR5U1_QG4s?si=O603Qii9ELt_y8X-
Additionally, I have tried 2 different plugins but nothing.
My website is leotechpty.com
I would appreciate it if you could help me with this problem.
I attach two additional images: loop on my webpage   and on my template
I tried to guide myself and replicate what I saw in YouTube videos like the one mentioned or try to follow these tips:
https://github.com/elementor/elementor/issues/25253
But I don't know much or almost nothing about programming so there are things I don't understand (when they talk about CSS)
